# Should I install up rabbitmq on each VM if I'm not running it as its own service/vm?

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, azureservicebus, masstransit

We currently have 2 Azure Windows VMs with all of our applications installed on each instance. These are then load balanced.

For now this works well for us financially as we have multiple .NET core APIs, Angular clients and .NET full framework apps running all with relatively low loads at the moment so there's no need to separate them on to individual instances (although we will likely do this in the future).

We've recently developed a service bus integration using .NET core, rabbitmq and MassTransit to handle email and report generation (as these take a while to generate and slow the apps down). This all works great locally and I'm ready to deploy.

I wanted to use Azure Service Bus so we have a centralised and cost effective message broker but at the moment MassTransit doesn't support .NET core integrations with Azure Service Bus (and I don't want to switch our producer or consumers to full .NET). I believe this should be available in the near future.

So until MassTransit supports ASB I want to use rabbitmq and my plan was to install rabbitmq on each of our 2 VMs (not linked in anyway) and point the producers and consumers on those machines to the local version of rabbitmq (because if the VM is down the producer, consumer and broker would all be down anyway).

Is this the right approach or is there a better way for me to configure rabbitmq for this scenario without paying for another instance/hosted service?

Answer (score 0):

The same as Azure SB, RabbitMQ is the message *broker*, which means you need one centralised instance. All your services will speak with this instance.

You can install it on any of your VMs, it does not take much RAM and you need just as much disk space as your queues require.

Comment: I know the ideal situation (and have got it installed and setup without any issues) but by installing it on just one VM does that not defeat the point of having the service load balanced because if that one VM goes down then so does the whole queue? What I'm looking for here is a stop gap, workable solution that enables us to have 2 instances of the producer and consumers so that we still have 100% of the services working if one server goes down.

Comment: Well, two RMQ instances would not give you load balancing unless you install them in a cluster. However, RMQ clustering is far from the best and you need to be more worrying about supporting all stuff that can come from it. I am not sure why do you expect your VMs going down thb.

Comment: I don't expect them to go down but I have to plan for it and also for restarts after certain OS updates. Our VMs are already load balanced so I thought (only as a temp measure) running a local queue for each VM would see me through the next 4 weeks (as the services on each VM would only use their local queues) but I was worried that I might be missing a trick.